# Hover over categorical axis

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

Is there a way to add more information to a categorical variable using plotly hover text?  For instance, if you take the plot below, is there a way to be able to hover over "A", "B", "C", or "D" on the x-axis to find out more about the groups?  I know how to add text to the individual points on the plot, but can't find anything about adding a definition or description of categorical variables

```
a<-data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=5), value=sample(1:40, size=20))  
ggplotly(ggplot(a, aes(x=group, y=value))+
   geom_point()+theme())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use plot_ly from library plotly and with text = specify any additional information you would like to appear:

```
 library(plotly)
  a<-data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=5), value=sample(1:40, size=20))  
  plot_ly(a, x=~group, y=~value,  type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', text =~paste("group: ",group))
```

Adding example to have list of all values at x-axis for each group

```
   library(tidyr)
    b<-a%>%
    group_by(group)%>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(value=0)
    c <- a%>%mutate(data="")%>%rbind(b)

  plot_ly(c, x=~group, y=~value,  type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', text = ~paste(data))
```

Comment: This is still changing text for the points.  I'm looking to have hover text over the categories themselves on the x-axis, so I can list something such what comprises the groups.  For instance, if you hover over "A" on the x-axis, I want text to say "Group A contains ____, ____, and ____" and so on for each group.  I don't know if this is possible